# Desktop resolution does not change when game resolution changes, result black borders

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, scaling

I'm using Windows 8.1 on my Asus N56VZ laptop with the latest graphics drivers installed (nVidia and Intel) and am having trouble when playing games where if I change the resolution of the game to that lower than the native resolution (1920x1080) the result is black borders around the game.

When I alt+tab out of the game, the resolution is still set as the native resolution whereas on my computer (running Windows 7), when I alt-tab the desktop resolution changes.

I have tried setting the scaling mode for the Intel Graphics Driver in the Advanced settings of the Screen Resolution settings panel to "Stretch to Fullscreen", but it seems to not work.

Any help would be appreciated, I've scoured forums over the internet to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the bios settings ?

Some computers with build-in graphics have a Bios setting for scaling non-native resolutions that overrides the scaling setting in the display-driver.

Comment: I know there's an option in the Intel Graphics Driver setting, but that's only visible when I set the resolution before entering a game - it's not permanent. nVidia used to have the option in "Adjust Screen Position", but thats now disappeared from the Control Panel.